# Remove browser specific style

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

Browsers have added additional functionality/styling to `input[type=number]` in the form of up and down buttons.

I was able to remove this styling in Chrome since we're able to view the shadow DOM and figure out an element's corresponding identity.

However, Firefox is another story. Is anybody aware of any way to remove the up and down buttons on `input[type=number]` in Firefox?

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490300/inspect-shadow-dom-with-firefox), but the extension wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* For Firefox */
input[type='number'] {
-moz-appearance:textfield;
}
/* Webkit browsers like Safari and Chrome */
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: perfect. thank you <3 how exactly did you find out about `-moz-appearance`?

Comment: MDN is our friend :-)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

Comment: i will, but there is a time limit restriction. also, i'm pretty sure `display:none` is sufficient for `...::-webkit-...`